# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Rx'

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

I am using angular CLI and visual studio code. 
my suggested import for Observable is 
`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/observable';`
although this does not import catch and throw.
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`
`import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'`
I went through a few issues raised which said to import from `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';`
But this gives me Error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Rx'.

`Node version : v8.9.4`

`npm version : 5.6.0`

I am just extremely new to angular and don't know what I am doing wrong or the corrective steps. 
Please help.

Comment: Which version of `rxjs` are you using?

Comment: If `rxjs` 6 go for  `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'` else `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`